# aws.logger.serilog key and secret configuration .netCore

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

so I added serilog for logging I was using it locally to log on files, but I want use serilog to update the logs on AWS cloud watch or add a log group on the cloud watch but I don't know where to add the secret and key or how to configure serilog to use them, should I add them as environment variables? what is the best practice?

**StartUp**

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

**appsettings.Develppment.json**

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "AWS.Logger.SeriLog" ],
    "Region": "us-west-2",
    "LogGroup": "AWS:Cloudwatch:LogGroup",
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "logs/logs_{Date}.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "logs/Test.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "logs/Test.json",
          //"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|{Level} => CorrelationID:{CorrelationID} => RequestId:{RequestId} => RequestPath:{RequestPath} => {SourceContext}{NewLine}    {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Program**

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("App Name", "example")
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting host");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }

        }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

        private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to add the configuration below to the appsettins.json file but here you are:

```
//...

using Amazon.Runtime;
using AWS.Logger;
using AWS.Logger.SeriLog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;
using Serilog.Formatting.Json;

// ...

// create a config object from the appsettings.json file
private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; } = new 
    ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

// ...

// you can get these configs from your appsettings.json
var awsS3sKey = Configuration["aws:access.key"];
var awsS3Secret = Configuration["aws:secret.key"];
var logGroupName = Configuration["aws:log.group.name"];
var region = Configuration["aws:log.region"];

// create your AWS credential
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsS3sKey, awsS3Secret);

// create a logger for AWS Cloudwatch
var awsConfiguration = new AWSLoggerConfig
{
    Region = region,
    LogGroup = logGroupName,
    Credentials = credentials
};

// create a serilog config
var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
    .WriteTo.AWSSeriLog(awsConfiguration, null, new JsonFormatter());

// logger is ready
Log.Logger = config.CreateLogger();

// ...
```

If you know how to add these settings to the appsettings file, please let me know.

By the way, I use these nuget packages below:

- AWS.Logger.SeriLog
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
- Serilog
- Serilog.Enrichers.Context
- Serilog.Extensions.Logging
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration
- Serilog.Sinks.Console
- Serilog.Sinks.File